# css transition with linear gradient

Tags: css-transitions, css

I'm trying to add a transition to a button I have that's background is made with css linear-gradient but it's not working.

This is the css for my button.

```
a.button
{
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,@green), color-stop(100%,#a5c956));
-webkit-transition: background 5s linear;
}

a.button:hover
{
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,@greenhover), color-stop(100%,#89af37))
}
```

If you're wondering about @green and @greenhover, I'm using .less to make my css.

Anything wrong with this? Any ideas?

Comment: **i just wanna hint to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48586471/4846859)** coz you gonna find all answers refers to opacity change and that's not satisfying.. hope you agree and y'all find it helps

Answer (score 51):

Sadly, you really can't transition gradients for now.

So, the only workable workaround is using an extra element with needed gradient and transition it's opacity:

```css
a.button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(green), to(#a5c956));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, green, #a5c956);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, green, #a5c956);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, green, #a5c956);
  background: linear-gradient(top, green, #a5c956);
}

.button-helper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(lime), to(#89af37));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, lime, #89af37);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, lime, #89af37);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, lime, #89af37);
  background: linear-gradient(top, lime, #89af37);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

a.button:hover .button-helper {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button"><span class="button-helper"></span>button</a>
```

Comment: This is dated, [psudo elements work fine](https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759) now

Comment: This doesn't always provide the same results. You can [use SVG](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36088098/2065702) to have a real transition instead

Comment: instead of even the svg solution i found this is so much satisfying [check my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48586471/4846859)

Answer (score 41):

#### it's tricky.. and of course tricky is cool ;)

okay.. i got a solution. and it's basically done via amazing `:before` selector

```css
#cool-hover{
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 margin: 0px auto 24px auto;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#cool-hover:before{
 border-radius: inherit;
 display: block;
 width: 200%;
 height: 200%;
 content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; 
        left: 0;
 background: linear-gradient(135deg, #21d4fd 25%, #b721ff 75%); 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 transform: translate(-25%, -25%);
 z-index: 0;
}
#cool-hover:after{
 border-radius: 9px;
 display: block;
 width: 108px;
 height: 108px;
 margin: 6px;
 background: url('https://i.imgur.com/w0BjFgr.png');
 background-size: cover;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
}
#cool-hover:hover:before{
 transform: translate(-25%, -25%) rotate(-180deg);
}
#cool-hover:hover{
 box-shadow: 0 0 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="cool-hover"></div>
```

---

> **NOTE** : i just added the `:after` sudo class just for the small on top image placeholder purpose..

have a nice awesome styling ;)

Answer (score 8):

I know this pretty old but I could not find any good solution yet. So here is my solution

First Make gradient on ":before and hide it with opacity then transition opacity 1 on hover.

https://jsfiddle.net/sumon380/osqLpboc/3/

```css
.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #d6e9eb;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-out;

}
.button:before {
    background: #91a5f4;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #91a5f4 0%, #b08cf9 86%);
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
.button:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">Button</a>
```

Comment: Best answer here!

Comment: It doesn't work for me unless I use `::before` instead of `:before`.

Comment: okay it could have some browser specific issue. why not use 
.button:before, .button::before

Answer (score 6):

You can fake gradient transitions using drop shadows!
For instance, from one of my pages:

```
c { 
color: #FFF;
background: #000;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#CCC;
border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555, inset 0 25px 20px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),
    inset 0 -15px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555, inset 0 25px 20px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),
    inset 0 -15px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555, inset 0 25px 20px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),
    inset 0 -15px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #555,
    inset 0 25px 20px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),
    inset 0 -15px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-moz-transition: background-color .5s ease; 
-o-transition: background-color .5s ease; 
-webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out; 
transition: background-color .5s ease;
}
```

Followed by:

```
c:hover {
color:#FFF;
background: #505;
position:relative;
top:1px;
box-shadow: -1px -1px -1px #555,inset 0 20px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 
        inset 0 -15px 20px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px -1px #555,inset 0 20px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
    inset 0 -15px 20px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
-o-box-shadow: -1px -1px -1px #555, inset 0 20px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 
        inset 0 -15px 20px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px -1px -1px #555, inset 0 20px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 
    inset 0 -15px 20px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

Here, you are essentially using an inset shadow as a Photoshop-like mask, causing a gradient effect on the underlying element. On hover, you invert the effect.

Comment: This has pretty horrid performance unless it's a very minor transition

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing the slight highlight when hovering the button there is a much simpler solution. You can just nudge the gradient down a bit and have the background-color be the same as the top color of your gradient: http://cdpn.io/oaByI

It's pretty limited I know, but if works well for that use case.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old, but I found a good way to animate basic gradients that will work in some cases.

This method will let you animate a change in color of the gradient but not a change in the position of the color stops.

https://jsfiddle.net/62vzydeh/

HTML:

```
<div class="button">
    Click Me!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button {

  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;

  margin: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;

  color: #C0C0C0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #F8F8F8, transparent 30%);
  background-color: #808080;

  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;

  cursor: pointer;

  transition: background-color 500ms;
}

.button:hover {

  background-color: #A0A0A0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a hacky way i tried was putting lots of `<spans>` to replicate "position", CSS only hack here: https://codepen.io/philipphilip/pen/OvXEaV

Answer (score 0):

9 years, but this time, hope my `styled-components` can help someone:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react'
import { Button as ButtonUI } from "@your-library-ui"
import styled from 'styled-components'

type Props = {
  onClick?: () => void;
  children?: ReactNode;
};

const Button = ({onClick, children}: Props) => (
  <StyledButton onClick={onClick} >
    {children}
    <ButtonHelper />
  </StyledButton>
)

export default Button

const ButtonHelper = styled.span`
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #5ab0f4, #1273ea)!important;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
`;

const StyledButton = styled(ButtonUI)`
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1273ea, #1c94f4)!important;
  color: #fff;
  &:hover ${ButtonHelper} {
    opacity: 1;
  }
`;
```

And start using your new designed component with extra effect! Thanks to @kizu for the suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

you must have same style in source and changed style in target.

like

```css
a {
   background: transparent;
   background: linear-gradient(transparent,transparent);
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
a:hover
{
   background: #abc07c;
   background: linear-gradient(#c5db95,#88a743);
}
```