# Javascript animate a style change using CSS3 transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that has a background gradient which values are set dynamically using javascript. Sometime, I need to change the gradient values (can be colors or color stop position). I would like to animate those changes without using javascript (dont get me wrong, I set the gradient valeus using javascript but I want to animate thise using CSS3). I tried setting a `transition` property like I would do with CSS. Here is a MWE:

```js
function getPercent() {
  return Math.random() * 100;
}
setInterval(() => {
  const per = getPercent();
  document.getElementById('foo').style.background =
    `linear-gradient(to right, #aebcbf 0%,#aebcbf ${per}%,#0a0e0a ${per}%,#0a0e0a 100%`
}, 1000)
```

```css
.container {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #aebcbf 0%,#6e7774 50%,#0a0e0a 51%,#0a0809 100%);
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css transition with linear gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363141/css-transition-with-linear-gradient) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds

Comment: @evolutionxbox I want the values to be originated from javascript, as the last edit now demonstrates, and the question is from 2011

Comment: The date of the question doesn't matter in this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds has your answer. CSS gradients are still non-animatable properties (transitions).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is useful

```
background: linear-gradient(269deg, #ffffff, #ff0000);
background-size: 400% 400%;
-webkit-animation: AnimationName 23s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: AnimationName 23s ease infinite;
-o-animation: AnimationName 23s ease infinite;
animation: AnimationName 23s ease infinite;
@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-o-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
```

- Ref: https://www.gradient-animator.com/

and for more info about CSS transition check this

- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Comment: This should be a comment, as you're not answering the question.

Comment: This is much better, but it still doesn't answer the question. The OP would like to animate the gradient using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `background-image` is not animatable (more [info about background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)). Therefore animating CSS gradients is an issue.

To solve this with pure CSS, you can create an `:before` that has contains the new gradient. Give it `opacity: 0` and change this to `opacity: 1` when you want to show the new gradient.

Eventually we can do the following:

```css
.container{
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #aebcbf 0%, #6e7774 50%, #0a0e0a 51%, #0a0809 100%);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
.container:before{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #aebcbf 0%, #6e7774 10%, #0a0e0a 51%, #0a0809 100%);
  content: '';    
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
  transition: opacity 0.45s;
}
.container:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="foo"></div>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to make the gradients dynamic use a variable that keeps track of which element you changed last, like:

```
var swapElement = 0;
function getPercent() {
  return Math.random() * 100;
}
setInterval(() => {
  const per = getPercent();
  if(swapElement == 0){
     //change gradient of :before
     //set opacity to 1
     swapElement = 1;
  } else {
     document.getElementById('foo').style.background =
    `linear-gradient(to right, #aebcbf 0%,#aebcbf ${per}%,#0a0e0a ${per}%,#0a0e0a 100%`
}, 1000);
     //set opacity :before to 0
     swapElement = 0;
  }
```

Comment: You can change the linear-gradients of the container and the before element. They can be completely dynamic.