# jQuery add and removeClass background with transition

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently setting my header that adding a class that changes the background to gradient.

Here is my code on adding and removing the class using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
            $('header').addClass('gradientHeader');         
        }else{
            $('header').removeClass('gradientHeader');
        }
    });    
});
```

and for **CSS**

```
.gradientHeader{
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #57cfb0, #2ab5d3);
    transition: background 0.3s;
}
```

my the adding and removing class is working but the transition on background isn't triggering..

working with .css with jquery is triggering the transition but it is with `background-color` and i want the specific color using `background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #57cfb0, #2ab5d3);`

```
$('gradientHeader').css("background-color", "red");
```

and workaround doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css transition with linear gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363141/css-transition-with-linear-gradient)

Comment: linear gradient on anchor links are good, what I am trying to do is changing the background after scroll event, the problem is that transition on linear gradient using jquery isn't triggering, It just snaps to linear without transition.. T_T

Comment: The problem is the same as the other thread - browsers cannot transition with `linear-gradient` the same way they can with background colors. The problem has nothing to do with jQuery in this case. You can apply a solution from that thread here. If you're having trouble, I'll create an answer below.

Comment: Hmm, that seems confusing and will on it.. T_T Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comments above, here's an answer to help you understand one method of doing this.

Using the `::before` pseudo-class, I've added the linear gradient background behind our div. When I say behind, I mean it's literally under the content and normal background color of the div, since it has `z-index: -1`.

Then the button is toggling a `.gradient` class on that div, which simply makes the normal background color transparent, thus revealing the gradient underneath. Transitioning between a color and `transparent` is supported by browsers.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('div').toggleClass('gradient');
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: teal;
  transition: background-color .5s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #57cfb0, #2ab5d3);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

div.gradient {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button>Toggle Gradient</button>
</div>
```